# inferred type is Fragment! but PlaceAutocompleteFragment was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, google-places-api

.xml :

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/paf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
    />
```

code :

```
val autocompleteFragment : PlaceAutocompleteFragment = paf
```

Error : type found is Fragment! , required is PlaceAutocompleteFragment
I've already tried SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment and .getActivity()
What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked :

```
val autocompleteFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.paf) as PlaceAutocompleteFragment
```

Answer (score 0):

When `paf` is inflated by default it is type Fragment when it is retrieved from the XML, what you need is to cast it to `PlaceAutocompleteFragment`.

`val autocompleteFragment : PlaceAutocompleteFragment = paf as PlaceAutocompleteFragment`

Comment: already tried, error : kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type PlaceAutocompleteFragment

Comment: @rotten_flesh Then make sure that `paf` variable is a non-null type, or unwrap the paf during casting

Comment: how do I make it non-null ?

Comment: @rotten_flesh `paf as? PlaceAutocompleteFragment`